# Python Function Works just fine but doesnt work when for looped

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, for-loop, pexpect

So I Created this function that changes a UNIX users password, and it works just fine but I want to for loop a list of users to change every users password. But the for loop doesn't work in the function, When i assign a variable for the same user in the list it works just not in the loop

**User.txt**

```
FakeAccount
FakeUser
```

**Python Function**

```
def change_password(username, new_password):
  process = pexpect.spawn("sudo passwd " + username)
  process.expect("Enter new UNIX password: ")
  process.sendline(new_password)
  process.expect("Retype new UNIX password: ")
  process.sendline(new_password)
  process.close()
```

**For Loop**

```
np = "test"
f = open('User.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    change_password(line.strip("\n\r"), np)
    print('done')
f.close()
```

What i'm trying to do is loop through the file and put that in place for the the username variable, when i run the code  there are no errors however when i try and to login into these accounts their passwords stay the same, When i run the python script i am root so that there are not sudo password prompts.

**What i think is the problem, from what I've tried**

I think the problem if somwhere in the process of for-looping the file because if i run this code it works perfectly

```
import pexpect
def change_password(username, new_password):
  process = pexpect.spawn("sudo passwd " + username)
  process.expect("Enter new UNIX password: ")
  process.sendline(new_password)
  process.expect("Retype new UNIX password: ")
  process.sendline(new_password)
  process.close()

np = "test"
U = "FakeUser"

change_password(U, np)
```

It's only when i introduce that for loop when i get an issue, and to my knowledge its grabbing the same username as i typed in my test Example because to test that i tried

```
f = open('User.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    print("'" + line.strip("\n\r") + "'")
```

and got the results 'FakeAccount' and 'FakeUser' which means the usernames are right, is it possible that the for loop is going to fast and not sending then through the terminal? or am i missing somthing?

Comment: Can you specify how the function doesn't work? Also, `pass` is a reserved keyword, I think it's invalid syntax to try to use it as a variable.

Comment: Because of the invalid `pass` variable you should be getting a syntax error before you even get to the loop.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a working example and some test data.

Comment: @Barmar I changed the variable im sorry that was an old test i put in there, now its up to date with the proper variables but its not changed the password

Comment: @zxxc i changed that i apologize, but it is now changed to the proper variable and im having issues with, some testing i did was to see if the line from the file is being typed right, for example i added a quotation mark at the beginning and end to see if it has any spaces or anything.

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(repr(username), repr(new_password))` in the function?

Comment: @Barmar which function the defining one or the one in the for loop?

Comment: I only see one function, `def change_password`. There's no function in the for loop.

Comment: Using `repr()` is better than your technique of printing with quotes around it.

Comment: @Barmar it gives me           ("'FakeAccount'", "'test'")
                                            ("'FakeUser'", "'test'")

Comment: Looks like you're using python 2.7. Can you try with Python 3.x?

Comment: @Barmar i used python 3 and got 'FakeAccount' 'root'
                                                       'FakeUser' 'root'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180965/discussion-between-lavarockman-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first sight, it seems to me that the problem is the file opening. Try with this:

```
np = "test"
with open('User.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    lines = [l for l in f.read().split("\n") if l]

for l in lines:
    change_password(l, np)
print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

So after many differnt tests and changing of things it works perfect now, the issue was i was needing to run it in python3 as well as giving it some time to process the commands, when i put a time.sleep(5) in the function is ran smoothly after that.